# does the setmainfont command path support ~

Tags: fonts

I want to add some custom font into my latex build process in macOS 13.3, this is the command I am using right now:

```
\setmainfont[
    Path = { /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.fonts/ },
  Extension = .otf ,
  BoldFont = HelveticaNeueLTPro-Md.otf ,
]{HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman.otf}
```

when I using the full path like this `/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.fonts/`, it works fine. But when I replace the path to `~/.fonts/`, the texstudio shows could not found the fonts. Does the setmainfont command path support the `~`? what should I do to fixed this issue?

Comment: why I replace the user path with ~, the xelatex could not found the fonts when compile?

Comment: sorry I meant no, you *can't* use `~`.  Install the fonts so that your system can find them, then xelatex and lualatex will find them too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use `~` for home, but you can use `\string~`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\fell}{IMFePIit29C}[
  Path=\string~/provaccia/conf-1.7b/fell/,
  Extension=.otf,
]

\begin{document}

{\fell Hello}

\end{document}
```

I found a rarely used font in some working directory. Here's the console output about the font (username masked), with LuaLaTeX

```
</Users/*******/provaccia/conf-1.7b/fell/IMFePIit29C.otf>
```

So you see it works. I also tested XeLaTeX with success.